# iPhone Simulator: setting custom resolution for iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, xcode, resolution, simulator, iphone-5

Is it possible to trick / hack iPhone Simulator in Xcode 4.4 for custom resolution to be able to start testing / developing application UI for new iPone 5 display  (1136 x 640px)?

Or do we have to patiently wait for newer tools release?

Comment: I believe there will be an update to Xcode with the release of iOS6 which will also include iPhone 5 simulator option

Comment: Why have this question been down-voted?

Comment: @chown How come that managing development tools has nothing to do with programming? There are many questions regarding setting up / tweaking IDEs / debugging tools / software distribution related questions and similar - and they are very useful for developers (even if they do not touch source code matters directly). There might be even development solution to the question (like python script) and that is directly programming related.

Comment: @chown: This is a question about a tool that only programmers will ever use. It is explicitly on topic.

Comment: Now that the new iOS Simulator is out and does this, this question is obsolete, so I'm closing it.

Comment: @chown I would love to hear explanation why do you believe this question is more off-topic than trivial questions asked multiple times by you: "What is the iOS 5.0 user agent string?" "What is the iOS 5.1 user agent string?" "What is the iOS 4.0 user agent string?" which are very loosely coupled to programming (if at all) and where solution to them is to only check it in the docs or webserver logs (solutions not related at all to the programming)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - solution http://0xced.blogspot.co.at/2012/08/prepare-your-apps-for-new-iphone.html

Comment: And of course, when we have Xcode 4.5 GM released now - you need just upgrade to it, use its simulator and when it starts select: iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Device -> iPhone (Retina 4-inch)