# Xcode 11 Simulator - How to customize simulated device resolution

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

#### Question:

In Xcode 11's simulator menu, there are only options for pre-defined Apple device models to choose from. Is there a way to create a simulated device with a custom resolution?

Note: I'm not asking for a way to scale the simulator interface, but a way to customize the device resolution.

#### My Attempts:

- [iPhone Simulator: setting custom resolution for iPhone 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395661/iphone-simulator-setting-custom-resolution-for-iphone-5) is out of date.

#### Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to create a simulated device with a custom resolution

Not any more. Years ago you could artificially create a pseudo-device with a custom screen size, but that ability is long gone. What you have now is all possible real-life screen size / resolutions.